# Целевой тип в лямбда-выражениях

Tags: java

У меня возникла небольшая путаница касательно понятия "целевой тип" в контексте лямбда-выражений.

Одно из определений: "Функциональный интерфейс , для которого было вызвано лямбда-выражение, называется целевым типом лямбда-выражения".

Другое:
"Целевым типом лямбда-выражения называется тип контекста, в котором это выражение встречается, – например, тип локальной переменной, которой оно присваивается, или тип параметра метода, вместо которого оно передается."

Как я понимаю, во-втором определении, имеется в виду ссылка на функциональный интерфейс, к которой может быть присвоена лямбда-выражение.
И вроде все сходится, но когда дело касается обобщений, то пишут следующее:

"При объявлении ссылки на функциональный интерфейс IValue< T > в аргументе типа нужно указать целевой тип лямбда-выражения".

В общем, что такое целевой тип в лямбда-выражениях?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Наверно, проще будет объяснить на примерах:

- Первое определение: *Функциональный интерфейс, для которого было вызвано лямбда-выражение, называется целевым типом лямбда-выражения*

```java
Runnable r = () -> System.out.println("Hi"); // целевой тип: Runnable
IntUnaryOperator sign = Integer::signum;     // целевой тип: IntUnaryOperator
IntBinaryOperator add = (a, b) -> a + b;     // целевой тип: IntBinaryOperator; a и b - int
```

Целевые типы -- интерфейсы, которые извлекаются из контекста.

- Второе определение: *При объявлении ссылки на функциональный интерфейс `IValue<T>` в аргументе типа нужно указать целевой тип лямбда-выражения*
  Данное определение приводится например здесь: [Лямбда-выражения для обобщенных функциональных интерфейсов. Примеры](https://www.bestprog.net/ru/2020/12/13/java-lambda-expressions-for-generic-functional-interfaces-examples-ru/) (англ. версия: [Lambda expressions for generic functional interfaces. Examples](https://www.bestprog.net/en/2020/12/13/java-lambda-expressions-for-generic-functional-interfaces-examples/))

```java
interface IValue<T> {
    T getValue();
}
```

Однако, здесь же сначала указывается: *В этом случае [если функциональный интерфейс является обобщённым] **целевой тип лямбда-выражения определяется на основании типа, указанного в ссылке на этот функциональный интерфейс**.*

Таким образом, *целевым типом лямбда-выражения* следует считать конкретизированный интерфейс (когда в ссылке указан конкретный класс), т.е. в приведённом примере таким типом будет `IValue<Float>`, тогда как `Float` является *аргументом типа (type argument)*.

```java
IValue<Float> refIValue = () -> 3.1415f; // Целевой тип IValue<Float>
```